# Microsoft Word - Column breaks too soon for no apparent reason

Tags: microsoft-word

### [image]

On one [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0twbE.png) in my document the column breaks too soon and leaves a blank space in the bottom left of the page. It breaks in the middle of a sentence and the only way to fill that space is to add more text at the top left of the page, which unfortunately isn't an option for me.
There are no column breaks or anything. What can I do to make it use that blank space and only break once it's full?

I'm using Office 365.

Comment: Hello, please make sure that this paragraph (bottom left) has "Keep with next" unchecked (second tab in the Paragraph dialog box).

Comment: Thank you! I had to play around a bit with those options a bit to get it right, but yes this was the problem :)